# Mysql query to find user details of all users who commented on a post?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, inner-join

I am new to sql joins. I have three tables: Users, Posts, Post_Comments. Every time a new user comments on a post its user_id along with post_id is saved in the Post_Comments table. Now I want to query the database which will find out names of all the users who have commented on a single post let's say whose id is 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like joins:

```
select u.*
from users u
inner join post_comments pc on pc.user_id = u.user_id
where pc.post_id = 2
```

If a user may comment more than once on a given post, you can use `exists` to avoid duplicates in the result set:

```
select u.*
from users u
where exists (
    select 1 from post_comments pc where pc.user_id = u.user_id and pc.post_id = 2
)
```